# Blazor Web Assembly Standalone JWT Authentication

Tags: c#, jwt, blazor-webassembly

In a custom authentication state provider in a blazor wasm standalone application, I am seeing [articles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider) that are writing as a second parameter "Fake authentication type". i.e.

```
List<Claim> claims = new();
ClaimsIdentity claimsId; 
claimsId = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Fake authentication type");
```

I know on a blazor server standalone project instead of using a place holder as the second parameter you can use the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`. I wanted to use this package but learned that it is not compatible with web assembly. Is there a package that is like Jwt package for wasm? If not, is there a reason why you would need to insert a placeholder for the second parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your q, you want to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` in place of "Fake authentication type", but can't reference the Nuget package.  You don't need to include that package, a hard-coded/fake string like "Fake authentication type" is fine.  The `AuthenticationScheme` parameter you reference is just a const string "Bearer" anyway.

The article you referenced is creating a custom authentication state provider for your Blazor app.  For example, let's pretend you only let users login when the weather is sunny (sunny days are your custom authentication state).  You could implement your custom auth state provider like this:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var weather = _weatherApi.GetWeather();
        if (weather == "Sunny")
        {
          // sunny day - return a "logged in" identity
          var fakeLoggedInIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
          {
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "mrfibuli"),
          }, "Fake authentication type");

          var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(fakeLoggedInIdentity);
          
          return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }
        else 
        {
           // rainy day - we are not logged in
           var notLogginInState 
                 = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            return Task.FromResult(notLoggedInState);
        }
}
```

The code above would allow your Blazor app to be "logged in" when it's sunny (the custom state).  This custom auth state provider will be connected to the Blazor `AuthorizeView` component below, with "mrfibuli" as the `Name`.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <h1>Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</h1>
    <p>You can only see this content if you're authenticated.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, it makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: Could someone (ahem, Steve) point me at a set-up guide to configuring my ASP.Net Core-hosted web assembly app to use JWT? All I see is AAD, Duende, AddApi this, AddAuthentication that, etc. ;-)

I'm using a pre-existing app (MS CRM) which I need to authenticate users against, so I have an API for that all set up, and I'm sure I can mimic the call to WeatherForecast above with that API, but it's what else is required in the server / client projects, especially when you're not using EntityFramework...